# window.alert() not displaying the input

Tags: javascript, html

im still new to html and learning it. right now my problem is that it wont display my input and i believe i done the code quite correctly but i could be wrong. im not sure whats wrong with it. thank you in advance!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>OVERSEAS VISITATION</title>
    
     <style>
        
        table, th, td {
           border: 1px solid black;
        }
     </style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
            v. oversea visit
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b> Student activities (overseas))</b> Max RM6000 :
            </td>
             <td>
                 <input type="text" name="visit">
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br><br>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="printOutput()">
</form>
<script> 
        
        function printOutput(){
            var rm = document.getElementByName('visit');
            window.alert("RM :"+visit);
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected code:

```
<form onsubmit="printOutput()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                v. oversea visit
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b> Student activities (overseas))</b> Max RM6000 :
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="visit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br><br>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>

    function printOutput(){
        var rm = document.getElementsByName('visit');
        window.alert("RM :"+ rm[0].value);
    }
</script>
```

Three things that you had to fix in your code :

1. onsubmit method is defined on the form, not on the submit input.
2. getElementByName is not a function, the function is getElementsByName which returns an array of all elements with the searched name property.
3. You must find the .value of the input to get the value entered in the input.

Comment: i never knew by missing an "s" could make a difference. thank you so much

Comment: Remember that any attribute which can hold the same value for multiple elements will be fetched by using getElementsBy and will return a list of the elements holding that value. Only getElementById is what returns a single element since id has to be unique for every element.

Answer (score 3):

There are some issues in you code:

1. Since the type of the button is submit, the form is submitting and you are losing the current page.
2. *getElementByName* is not correct, you are missing `s`, should be `getElementsByName`. And it returns collection, you have to use the proper *index*. Though, I prefer using `querySelector()`. Also, you have to take the `value` from the element.
3. You are not using the value of *rm* to show in the alert, instead you are using *visit* that causes an error.

Try the following way:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>OVERSEAS VISITATION</title>    
     <style>        
        table, th, td {
           border: 1px solid black;
        }
     </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
      <table>
          <tr>
              <th colspan="2">
              v. oversea visit
              </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <b> Student activities (overseas))</b> Max RM6000 :
              </td>
               <td>
                   <input type="text" name="visit">
               </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="printOutput()">
  </form>
  <script>         
    function printOutput(){
      var rm = document.querySelector('[name=visit]').value;
      window.alert("RM :"+rm);
    }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i kinda overlook that. but thank you for correcting me. really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Change input type submit to button and in the javascript use value

Comment: Adding a code example would make this answer more useful.